# make a shape watetight using trimesh

Tags: python, trimesh

We are trying to make a shape to be watertight, we are using trimesh library. However, neither trimesh.repair.fill_holes nor meshlab's filter is giving good results.

We have the same problem as:

[Complete a partial mesh and make it watetight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65065925/complete-a-partial-mesh-and-make-it-watetight)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Complete a partial mesh and make it watetight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65065925/complete-a-partial-mesh-and-make-it-watetight)